# How do I reference a visualforce page from a managed package?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, url

I am running into a problem with a lightning component in a managed packaged that is loading a visual force page from the same managed package, but both are being loading in a lightning page in a 2nd manual package.

I have enabled the [critical update for all orgs involved that removes the instance from the url for visual force pages](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_vf_instance_names_removed.htm).  I believe that the format for this is now `https://<mydomain>--<namespace>.visualforce.com/apex/<namespace>__<pagename>`

In the package where the visual force page was created, both namespaces being the namespace of the managed package works fine as expected.  When it is loaded into the second managed package is where I am having a problem.  To simplify what comes next, I'll refer to the managed package where the visual force page was created as base and the the package where I am trying to load it as addon.

1. `https://<mydomain>--<base>.visualforce.com/apex/<base>__<pagename>`
   results in the message An internal server error has occurred.
2. `https://<mydomain>--<addon>.visualforce.com/apex/<base>__<pagename>`
   results in an error that this page can not be reached.
3. `https://<mydomain>--<base>.visualforce.com/apex/<addon>__<pagename>`
   results in an error that this page can not be reached.
4. `https://<mydomain>--<addon>.visualforce.com/apex/<addon>__<pagename>`
   results in an error that this page can not be reached.

I was certain that option 2 would be correct, but it seems like option 1 is the only way, but it still fails and I can't find out why.  Does anyone have experience with the new URLs in managed packages?

Comment: Have you tried to navigate using relative URLs? i.e. `/apex/namespace__pagename`, Salesforce will handle the redirects to the VF domain.

Comment: Yes, I have tried `/apex/<base>__<pagename>` along with `/apex/<pagename>` and `/apex/<addon>__<pagename>`

Comment: I did change the url in the base package to `/apex/<base>__<pagename>` and deployed this change.  This now results in the error message instead of the reuslts that a page can not be reached.